# jQuery redefined by requirejs in legacy app

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I've been assigned a task developing a small app for a legacy page to replace a flash app in place right now.

I've developed this app using requirejs, knockout and jquery, but it seems that when using the setup I have, all registered change events on some textareas in the app, is unregistered. The behaviour can be illustrated with this simple html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#container .input").change(function() {
                console.log($(this).val());
            });
            console.log($("#input").data("events"));
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.6/comments/require.js"></script>
    <script>
        require.config({
            paths: {
                jquery: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min",
            },
            shim: {
                jquery: {
                    exports: "$"
                }
            }
        });

        require(
            ["jquery"],
            function($) {
                console.log("starting");
                console.log($("#input").data("events"));
            }
        );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <input type="text" id="input" class="input" />
    </div>
</body>
```

This code will report events attached to the input element on first call, but as undefined on second. I need the attached events to stay in place, since there's some legacy code autosaving the content of the (hidden) input field I update.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you may have an error in the code. The selector `"#container .input"` refers to a class of `input`, whereas the other code refers to `#input`, i.e. the id `input`.

[The following jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/TdV5E/3/) will work as intended.

The example doesn't use RequireJS to load jQuery at all. Instead, it `define`s the `jquery` module explicitly, after loading jQuery with a regular `<script>` tag.

*This will ensure that the global jQuery object and the AMD `jquery` module value are one and the same thing. Therefore keeping a single jQuery to register events with, etc.*

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.6/comments/require.js"></script>
<script>define("jquery", function() { return jQuery; });</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("page onready");
    var inputs = $("#container .input");
    console.log(inputs.length);
    inputs.keypress(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
    console.log($(".input").data("events"));
});
</script>
<script>
require(["jquery"], function($) {
    console.log("module starting");
    $(function() {
        console.log("module onready");
        console.log($(".input").data("events"));
    });
});
</script>
<div id="container"><input class="input" type="text" /></div>
```

Keep in mind this example is intended to be close to yours. If it were me, I would remove the jQuery `<script>` tag and use RequireJS shim to pull in jQuery.

Whether you can do this or not depends on the rest of your application.

In which case

- You couldn't use the 'naked' `$` or `jQuery` objects (at least not until RequireJS has loaded it - in which case you should be using AMD syntax, see next).
- Any use of jQuery should be restricted to within a `require` or `define` call.
- The jQuery `<script>` tag is removed (we don't want jQuery loading twice; once by the `<script>` tag and once by RequireJS shim).

E.g.:

```
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.6/comments/require.js"></script>
<script>
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min",
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: "$"
        }
    }
});
</script>
<script>
require(["jquery"], function($) {
    $(function() {
        console.log("page onready");
        var inputs = $("#container .input");
        console.log(inputs.length);
        inputs.keypress(function() {
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
        console.log($(".input").data("events"));
    });
});
</script>
<script>
require(["jquery"], function($) {
    console.log("module starting");
    $(function() {
        console.log("module onready");
        console.log($(".input").data("events"));
    });
});
</script>
<div id="container"><input class="input" type="text" /></div>
```

Comment: Nice elaborate answer. As much as I'd have liked to, it wasn't possible for me to use the second approach, since I didn't have control over the rest of the scripts. Ended up not referencing jquery _at all_ in my own modules, which also worked. I think your top solution is better though since it's more expressive.